# MYSQL y PHP soy nuevo en esto y me gustaria su sabiduria

Tags: php, mysql

estoy aprendiendo sql y php en el instituto y me gustaria saber como puedo hacer para utilizar la funcion **SELECT**  u[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]  **OPTION** (no estoy segudo) de html para que me muestre los datos de mi DB y a su vez tambien utilizarlos para rellenar formularios.

`

```
<td><label>Tablas: </label></td>
 <td><select name="" id="">
 <option value="0">selecciona Tabla</option>
 <?php
 $query = $conexion -> query ("SELECT DISTINCT tipo_producto from producto");
 while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {echo '<option value="'.$valores[0].'">'.$valores[0].'</option>';}
?>
</select></td>
```

`

Comment: es verdad no estoy seguro.. pero es la barra q se desplaza con las opciones sql

Comment: ¿arroja algún mensaje de error? Lo digo por saber como está definida $conexión (de hecho, estas utilizando programación orientada en objetos mezclado con programación procedimental y eso me despista un poco)

Comment: no me sale error, lo que quiero saber es como utilizar los items dentro de OPTION para completar un formulario..